# CreateObject randomly fails since recent windows security update that does not seem related

Tags: asp-classic, createobject, browscap

We use MSWC.BrowserType (browscap.dll) in our classic asp website to help identify user agents.

Since July 21 our code began to throw Server.CreateObject failed errors when trying to create this object.
It works most of the time, but randomly fails several times each day.

I was on vacation when the problem began, I know we didn't change anything in our code or system configuration, the only thing I see is the windows update kb3079904 that was installed on the July 21, but it does not seems related because it is about font driver !?

I wonder if someone else have the same problem or have an idea how to solve it, I did some research about intermittent createobject failing but didn't find anything relevant.

I may try to restore the system to the checkpoint before this update to see if it is really the cause, but this is an important security update and I will have to re-install it after so it may not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be related to this other post, object creation failed because the component likely uses the cookie collection.

[Response.Cookies collection seems corrupted and causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840857/response-cookies-collection-seems-corrupted-and-causes-error/31842253#31842253)